# Pulling limit inside $L^\infty$ norm?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

I want to prove that $||\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n||_\infty\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}||f_n||_\infty$ if both limits exist.  I know that for $L^p$ one can use Fatou's lemma, but I'm not sure how to do it in the $L^\infty$ case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L^\infty$ is much simpler than $L^p$ in certain aspects. For a.e. $x$ and each $n$, $|f_n(x)| \le ||f_n||_\infty$. Hence, $\lim_n |f_n(x)| \le \lim_n ||f_n||_\infty$. Since this holds for a.e. $x$, $||\lim_n f_n||_\infty \le \lim_n ||f_n||_\infty$.

Comment: I think there are two problems here.  For each should be "For almost every" and $f_n(x)$ should be $|f_n(x)|$.  If you fix those, I can accept this answer.

Comment: You are right about the absolute value thing but you never mentioned almost everywhere. In any case, I fixed.

Comment: Almost everywhere is part of the definition of $L^\infty$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-infinity.

Comment: @mlstudent ah, my apologies